# How to convert this SQL statement to HQL

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

I got a following SQL statement:

```
SELECT p.category_id, COUNT(p.id)
FROM products p
WHERE p.name ILIKE 'product%'
GROUP BY p.category_id
```

and i want to convert it to HQL of this entity:

Product:

```
private Long id;

@NotNull
private String name;

@NotNull
private String description;

@NotNull
private String image;

@NotNull
private Double price;

@ManyToOne
private Category category;
```

what i got is:

```
@Query("SELECT p.category.id, COUNT(p.id) " +
        "FROM Product p " +
        "WHERE p.name LIKE ?1 " +
        "GROUP BY p.category.id")
List<SearchDetail> findSearchDetailsByName(String phrase);
```

but it's giving me the following error:
https://pastebin.com/h4yBPc7d

- Product repository: https://pastebin.com/S96Bcgvm
- SearchDetail: https://pastebin.com/Hnfnd2ra

Comment: First of all are you using spring data ? else you query should look like `@Query(nativeQuery = true, value="SELECT p.category_id, COUNT(p.id) as var FROM products p WHERE p.name LIKE: name GROUP BY p.category_id")
List<SearchDetail> findSearchDetailsByName(@Param("name")String phrase);`

Comment: Your SearchDetail is an jpa entity ? or just a simple pojo ?

Comment: Sure I'm using spring-data, this is my repository: https://pastebin.com/S96Bcgvm and SearchDetail is an POJO : https://pastebin.com/Hnfnd2ra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this :

```
@Query("SELECT new com.cm.sb.SearchDetail(p.category.id as category, COUNT(p.id) as count)  " +
            "FROM Product p " +
            "WHERE p.name LIKE ?1 " +
            "GROUP BY p.category.id")
    List<SearchDetail> findSearchDetailsByName(String phrase);
```

As you see you have to specify the package of `SearchDetail` in the query.

Nb: i have tested the solution and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just need to give aliases to the selected columns in your query that match the field names in your `SearchDetail` pojo:

```
@Query("SELECT p.category.id AS category, COUNT(p.id) AS count" +
    "FROM Product p " +
    "WHERE p.name LIKE ?1 " +
    "GROUP BY p.category.id")
List<SearchDetail> findSearchDetailsByName(String phrase);
```

Comment: Don't works, still the same error:
`Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Product is not mapped [SELECT p.category.id AS category, COUNT(p.id) AS count FROM Product p WHERE p.name LIKE ?1 GROUP BY p.category.id]`

Comment: That error message looks like you don't have a mapped `Product` entity, what does your `Product` class look like?